# Is it possible to add more fields to admin/auth/user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
class UserProfile(User):
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    pfp = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Profile Picture', blank=True, null=True, upload_to="images/profile")
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder":"example@example.com"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    pfp = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    bio = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control", 'rows':5, "placeholder":"Write something about yourself..."}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', "pfp", "bio"]
```

When creating the user, the two newly added fields (bio and pfp) are not being saved in admin/auth/user, so my question is, is it possible to add those fields to the admin users database?

views.py

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    template_name = "registration/signup.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
```

Comment: Can you share the view?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just added it.

Answer (score 1):

> are not being saved in admin/auth/user

Indeed, these are safed on the `UserProfile` model.

You thus can make a `ModelAdmin` for this:

```
# app_name/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from app_name.models import UserProfile


@admin.register(UserProfile)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'pfp', 'bio')
```

Then the details can be seen in the `admin/app_name/userprofile` section.

Comment: Thanks, but the value for image is not being saved in the database. Also, when I try to edit the profile using EditProfileForm form and UserEditView view, the values for both bio and pfp do not show. Im returning the following in the edit view:
def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user, what could be the problem?

Comment: @AdryanZeigler: likely you forgot the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag. For the `get_object`, you will need `self.request.user.userprofile`..

Comment: When I changed it to user.userprofile, it only saved the bio, but did not save the fields taken from user (username, email, etc) nor the image. Is there a way to make userprofile a part of user? Also thanks a lot for trying to help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Everything works well now except for the image, it doesnt seem to be saved (even after adding the enctype to the form)

Comment: It worked all good now, I had to change the whole view and pass in "request.FILES" to       profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom user model by inheriting the `AbstractUser` and adding extra fields needed. After that, register that custom user model by assigning it to [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL).

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) for detailed implementation.